# Why does `select *, column from table;` work but `select column, * from table;` not work

Tags: mysql, sql

Sometimes its handy to return all data in a table as well as the data you specifically want e.g.

```
SELECT *, name, age FROM users;
```

But it would be more handy to get the data you want first, followed by the remaining data.

```
SELECT name, age, * FROM users;
```

However the second SQL statement fails with a syntax error.

Why is this?

Comment: [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html): "Use of an unqualified `*` with other items in the select list may produce a parse error. To avoid this problem, use a qualified `tbl_name.*` reference".

Comment: I've searched a bit around with what @Damien_The_Unbeliever provided. Interestingly there is *nothing* beyond 'this may produce a parse error'. There is not even an explanation on what kind of parse error this could result in or where that would occur. In 2007 a [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26066) was filed for this and closed with the exact same explanation two years later.

Comment: According to ANSI/ISO SQL, if an unqualified  `*` is used, it must be alone in the select list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've searched a bit and I found a total of 3 questions on SO that are related to this question or pose the same question. Disclaimer: I only found them by searching for something from the link Damien provided in the comments: `"Use of an unqualified * with other items"`

You get these SO questions:

- [Why does adding '*' to a MySQL query cause a syntax error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922254/why-does-adding-to-a-mysql-query-cause-a-syntax-error)
- [Using count(*) and * in the same select clause gives an error. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422680/using-count-and-in-the-same-select-clause-gives-an-error-why)
- [Confusing SQL error in SELECT NULL, *, NULL, NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096336/confusing-sql-error-in-select-null-null-null)

In the comments on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25096378/937093) of the last question I found a link to a [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26066) from 2007 which was closed in 2009 with the following explanation:

> I have updated http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html to
>   reflect the behavior:
>
> A select list consisting only of a single unqualified * can be used as
>   shorthand to select all columns from all tables:
>
> SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ...
>
> tbl_name.* can be used as a qualified shorthand to select all columns
>   from the named table:
>
> SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ...
>
> **Use of an unqualified * with other items in the select list may**
>   **produce a parse error.** To avoid this problem, use a qualified
>   tbl_name.* reference
>
> SELECT AVG(score), t1.* FROM t1 ...

Highlight/Bold provided by me. I couldn't find any further explanation for this behaviour or what kind of parse error could occur or where it would occur.

If someone has some time this could be answered by digging into MySQL's or MariaDB's (which has the same behaviour) source code but short of that I don't see someone finding a real answer to this.

Comment: Thanks for your summary of the various information. +1

Answer (score 0):

Because mysql is lenient to its syntax, but not always...

Beside, if you want to write a valid SQL query, it should be like that:

```
select col1, col2, users.* 
from users
```

Or with alias on table and column:

```
select u.*, 'foobar' as col1, 1 as col2
from users u
```